# Set min-width using tailwind spacing units without global config?

Tags: tailwind-css

Is there a way to apply spacified spacing units from `tailwind.config.js` to e.g. `min-width` other than by global config? That's as far I can see the only way but would mean to duplicate all (necessary) spacing units which is from my pov a potential error source as each relevant space must get duplicated then.

```css
// Dummy code explaining what I want to achieve
.myButton{
  @apply bg-red-100 w-auto;
      
  min-width: @apply w-11 // Not working just for theoretical explanation 
     
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll provide every known option for me

**1**. Provide value inside config

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      minWidth: {
        11: '2.75rem'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will generate `min-w-11` class with `min-width: 2.75rem`. But what if for some reason Tailwind change `11` value to let say `197px`, how can we sync it? Well every option has access to default theme options like

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      minWidth: theme => ({
        11: theme('spacing[11]')
      })
    }
  }
}
```

This time `min-w-11` will set `min-width: 197px;`. It referenced [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#referencing-other-values)

**2**. Use `theme()` directive
It is works inside CSS files like - no need to set config unless you need new value which is not present in default theme

```
.myButton{
  @apply bg-red-100 w-auto;
  min-width: theme('spacing[11]'); // 2.75rem
}
```

More information about `theme()` directive [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#theme)

**3**. With a JIT mode enabled - requires Tailwind version 2.1 or higher

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit'
}
```

This on its own will generate CSS properties on the fly

```
<button class="myButton min-w-[2.75rem]">My Button</button>
<button class="myButton min-w-[197px]">My Button</button>
```

generated properties are

```
.min-w-\[2\.75rem\] {
    min-width: 2.75rem;
}
.min-w-\[197px\] {
    min-width: 197px;
}
```

You can read about JIT [here](https://blog.tailwindcss.com/tailwindcss-2-1#jit-engine-in-core)

Please let me know if my answer is not what are you looking for as I may misunderstood question

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ihar Aliakseyenka  `min-width: theme('spacing[11]');`was exactly what I was looking for. Just figured out also  `min-width: theme('spacing.11');` is working

Comment: True but I feel little bit safer as it will not work with dotted values like `theme('spacing.2.5')`. Like it more universal

Answer (score 1):

`min-w-[theme('spacing[11]')]` also works, tested in Tailwind v3.